# RSA decrypt error

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt file with small string with RSA.
After encrypting string, program writes to a file private key and crypted text.

Code to encrypt:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096);
string pub = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
string priv = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
string to_crypt = "Hello world, try to crypt me";

byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(to_crypt);
rsa.FromXmlString(pub);
dataToEncrypt = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false);

string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
WriteFile("crypt", priv+s);
```

Another program reads text in array and tries to decrypt:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(4096))
{
byte[] to_decrypt = File.ReadAllBytes(args[0]);
byte[] key = new byte[3219];
byte[] text = new byte[to_decrypt.Length - key.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(to_decrypt, 0, key, 0, key.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(to_decrypt, key.Length, text, 0, text.Length);

string skey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key, 0, key.Length);
rsa.FromXmlString(skey);
rsa.Decrypt(text, false);        <---- Error: Bad data
    ...
```

I've got error:

> CryptographicException:Bad data

I made mistake in text array? Wrong size of array?

Comment: You need to post your encryption code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest possible mistake: You're writing a newline at the end of your file, and that newline is being read into `to_decrypt`/`text`, making it two (on Windows) bytes bigger than the actual ciphertext.  Compare the length of `dataToEncrypt` (when it's already encrypted) and `text`.

As Maarten already said, and many of us have said innumerable times, there aren't strings in (real/modern) cryptography, just bytes.  Base64 is a stable way of sending bytes over a text stream, when that's a requirement.  Your other source of error could be that you're getting a `\0` in your text interpretation of the "ciphertext" (which isn't text, but a legacy name from character-based encryption) and it's not round-tripping the way you hope or expect.  I don't think this is your current problem, though, since you're handing the data separation as bytes.

And, just as an FYI: The XML based key export/import don't work in .NET Core, you should use the `RSAParameters`-based `ImportParameters`/`ExportParameters` instead.

Answer (score 0):

RSA encrypts to ciphertext, which is not UTF-8 but a byte array without any character encoding.

If you want to transport it over a text interface then you should base 64 encode after encryption and base64 decode before decryption.

You can of course also just create a binary file with the encrypted contents.

---

This during encrypt:

```
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
```

and this during decrypt:

```
byte[] key = new byte[3219];
byte[] text = new byte[to_decrypt.Length - key.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(to_decrypt, 0, key, 0, key.Length);
Buffer.BlockCopy(to_decrypt, key.Length, text, 0, text.Length);
...
string skey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(key, 0, key.Length);
```

is all stuff you don't want nor need.